# Video buffering when trying to play it flutter dart

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-video-player, flutter-video-player

I am trying to create a dog photo/video generator app using Flutter and Dart. It basically sends a get request to a website called [random.Dog](http://random.dog/woof.json) to get a url to show on my app. Sometimes the url is a video and sometimes it is a img. When it is a video my app just buffers and this console message keeps on coming:

```
E/flutter ( 4345): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: 

MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method init on channel better_player_channel)
E/flutter ( 4345): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:156:7)
E/flutter ( 4345): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 4345): 
E/flutter ( 4345): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method create on channel better_player_channel)
E/flutter ( 4345): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:156:7)
E/flutter ( 4345): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 4345): #1      MethodChannel.invokeMapMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:358:43)
E/flutter ( 4345): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 4345): #2      MethodChannelVideoPlayer.create (package:better_player/src/video_player/method_channel_video_player.dart:38:9)
E/flutter ( 4345): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 4345): #3      VideoPlayerController._create (package:better_player/src/video_player/video_player.dart:202:18)
E/flutter ( 4345): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 4345): 
I/flutter ( 4345): {"fileSizeBytes":3294982,"url":"https://random.dog/a922da9a-437c-4400-9d94-f36ec2e5452c.mp4"}
D/CCodecBuffers( 4345): [c2.android.aac.decoder#768:1D-Input.Impl[N]] codec released a buffer owned by client (index 2)
D/BufferPoolAccessor2.0( 4345): bufferpool2 0xeac5e4a8 : 5(40960 size) total buffers - 5(40960 size) used buffers - 1/7 (recycle/alloc) - 6/45600 (fetch/transfer)
D/CCodecBuffers( 4345): [c2.android.aac.decoder#768:1D-Input.Impl[N]] codec released a buffer owned by client (index 0)
I/CCodecConfig( 4345): query failed after returning 19 values (BAD_INDEX)
D/CCodecConfig( 4345): c2 config diff is   c2::i32 coding.drc.compression-mode.value = 3
W/Codec2Client( 4345): query -- param skipped: index = 1342179345.
W/Codec2Client( 4345): query -- param skipped: index = 2415921170.
W/Codec2Client( 4345): query -- param skipped: index = 1610614798.
D/CCodecBuffers( 4345): [c2.android.aac.decoder#768:Output[N]] popFromStashAndRegister: output format changed to AMessage(what = 0x00000000) = {
D/CCodecBuffers( 4345):   int32_t aac-drc-album-mode = 0
D/CCodecBuffers( 4345):   int32_t aac-drc-boost-level = 127
D/CCodecBuffers( 4345):   int32_t aac-drc-cut-level = 127
D/CCodecBuffers( 4345):   int32_t aac-drc-effect-type = 3
D/CCodecBuffers( 4345):   int32_t aac-drc-heavy-compression = 3
D/CCodecBuffers( 4345):   int32_t aac-drc-output-loudness = -1
D/CCodecBuffers( 4345):   int32_t aac-encoded-target-level = -1
D/CCodecBuffers( 4345):   int32_t aac-max-output-channel_count = 8
D/CCodecBuffers( 4345):   int32_t aac-target-ref-level = 64
D/CCodecBuffers( 4345):   int32_t channel-count = 1
D/CCodecBuffers( 4345):   string mime = "audio/raw"
D/CCodecBuffers( 4345):   int32_t sample-rate = 44100
D/CCodecBuffers( 4345): }
D/CCodecConfig( 4345): c2 config diff is   c2::i32 coding.drc.compression-mode.value = 1
D/CCodecBuffers( 4345): [c2.android.aac.decoder#768:Output[N]] popFromStashAndRegister: output format changed to AMessage(what = 0x00000000) = {
D/CCodecBuffers( 4345):   int32_t aac-drc-album-mode = 0
D/CCodecBuffers( 4345):   int32_t aac-drc-boost-level = 127
D/CCodecBuffers( 4345):   int32_t aac-drc-cut-level = 127
D/CCodecBuffers( 4345):   int32_t aac-drc-effect-type = 3
D/CCodecBuffers( 4345):   int32_t aac-drc-heavy-compression = 1
D/CCodecBuffers( 4345):   int32_t aac-drc-output-loudness = -1
D/CCodecBuffers( 4345):   int32_t aac-encoded-target-level = -1
D/CCodecBuffers( 4345):   int32_t aac-max-output-channel_count = 8
D/CCodecBuffers( 4345):   int32_t aac-target-ref-level = 64
D/CCodecBuffers( 4345):   int32_t channel-count = 1
D/CCodecBuffers( 4345):   string mime = "audio/raw"
D/CCodecBuffers( 4345):   int32_t sample-rate = 44100
D/CCodecBuffers( 4345): }
D/BufferPoolAccessor2.0( 4345): bufferpool2 0xeac5e4a8 : 5(40960 size) total buffers - 5(40960 size) used buffers - 1/7 (recycle/alloc) - 6/45824 (fetch/transfer)
D/CCodecBuffers( 4345): [c2.android.aac.decoder#768:1D-Input.Impl[N]] codec released a buffer owned by client (index 1)
D/CCodecBuffers( 4345): [c2.android.aac.decoder#768:1D-Input.Impl[N]] codec released a buffer owned by client (index 0)
I/chatty  ( 4345): uid=10154(com.example.randomdog) HwBinder:4345_1 identical 4 lines
D/CCodecBuffers( 4345): [c2.android.aac.decoder#768:1D-Input.Impl[N]] codec released a buffer owned by client (index 0)
D/BufferPoolAccessor2.0( 4345): bufferpool2 0xeac5e4a8 : 5(40960 size) total buffers - 5(40960 size) used buffers - 1/7 (recycle/alloc) - 6/46039 (fetch/transfer)
D/CCodecBuffers( 4345): [c2.android.aac.decoder#768:1D-Input.Impl[N]] codec released a buffer owned by client (index 3)
D/CCodecBuffers( 4345): [c2.android.aac.decoder#768:1D-Input.Impl[N]] codec released a buffer owned by client (index 4)
D/BufferPoolAccessor2.0( 4345): bufferpool2 0xeac5e4a8 : 5(40960 size) total buffers - 5(40960 size) used buffers - 1/7 (recycle/alloc) - 6/46268 (fetch/transfer)
D/CCodecBuffers( 4345): [c2.android.aac.decoder#768:1D-Input.Impl[N]] codec released a buffer owned by client (index 2)
D/CCodecBuffers( 4345): [c2.android.aac.decoder#768:1D-Input.Impl[N]] codec released a buffer owned by client (index 0)
D/CCodecBuffers( 4345): [c2.android.aac.decoder#768:1D-Input.Impl[N]] codec released a buffer owned by client (index 1)
D/BufferPoolAccessor2.0( 4345): bufferpool2 0xeac5e4a8 : 5(40960 size) total buffers - 5(40960 size) used buffers - 1/7 (recycle/alloc) - 6/46498 (fetch/transfer)
D/CCodecBuffers( 4345): [c2.android.aac.decoder#768:1D-Input.Impl[N]] codec released a buffer owned by client (index 3)
D/CCodecBuffers( 4345): [c2.android.aac.decoder#768:1D-Input.Impl[N]] codec released a buffer owned by client (index 0)
D/CCodecBuffers( 4345): [c2.android.aac.decoder#768:1D-Input.Impl[N]] codec released a buffer owned by client (index 4)
D/CCodecBuffers( 4345): [c2.android.aac.decoder#768:1D-Input.Impl[N]] codec released a buffer owned by client (index 0)
I/CCodecConfig( 4345): query failed after returning 19 values (BAD_INDEX)
D/CCodecConfig( 4345): c2 config diff is   c2::i32 coding.drc.compression-mode.value = 3
W/Codec2Client( 4345): query -- param skipped: index = 1342179345.
W/Codec2Client( 4345): query -- param skipped: index = 2415921170.
W/Codec2Client( 4345): query -- param skipped: index = 1610614798.
D/CCodecBuffers( 4345): [c2.android.aac.decoder#768:Output[N]] popFromStashAndRegister: output format changed to AMessage(what = 0x00000000) = {
```

And my video doenst show up on my emulator. What seems to be the problem and how do I fix it? My minimal code:

```
import 'package:better_player/better_player.dart';


void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: RandomDog()));

class RandomDog extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RandomDogState createState() => _RandomDogState();
}

class _RandomDogState extends State<RandomDog> {
  var headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'};
  var body = {};
  var video = false;
  var img = false;
  var message;
  var loading = true;
  var _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    getDog();
    super.initState();
  }

  getDog() async {
    loading=true;
    var response = await http.get(Uri.https('random.dog', '/woof.json'));
    print(response.body);
    message = jsonDecode(response.body);
    if (message['url'].contains('gif') || message['url'].contains('png') ||
        message['url'].contains('jpg') || message['url'].contains('jpeg')) {
      video = false;
      img = true;
    } else {
      video = true;
      img = false;
    }
    loading = false;
    setState(() {

    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        . . .
      body: Center(
        child: loading == true ? CircularProgressIndicator() : Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Visibility(visible: img,
                child: Image.network(message['url'], fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,)),
            // Visibility(visible: video,child: VideoApp(url:message['url'])),
            video == true? CircularProgressIndicator() :
                Visibility(visible: video, child: BetterPlayer.network(message['url'],betterPlayerConfiguration: BetterPlayerConfiguration(autoPlay: true),)), //Chewie(controller: _controller,)
            
            OutlinedButton(onPressed: () async {
              getDog();
            }, child: Text('GENERATE')),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this solution work for you, Try to initialize your betterPlayer in your function getDog()  by using :

```
BetterPlayerController _betterPlayerController; //declare first

 BetterPlayerDataSource betterPlayerDataSource = BetterPlayerDataSource(
    BetterPlayerDataSourceType.network,
    "message[url]");
_betterPlayerController = BetterPlayerController(
    BetterPlayerConfiguration(),
    betterPlayerDataSource: betterPlayerDataSource);
```

after that in your widget after CircularProgressIndicator you add this :

```
BetterPlayer(
        controller: _betterPlayerController,  ),
```

Comment: The same error occurs and I did those changes. Is there any other changes that could be done @GirlWhoCode

Comment: try to clean and uninstal the app and rebuild   !!

Comment: if i want to use this inside listview.builder then?